# Convert columns i to j to percentage

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have the following data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(name=c("A1","A1","B1","B1"),
                  somevariable=c(0.134,0.5479,0.369,NA),
                  othervariable=c(0.534, NA, 0.369, 0.3333))
```

In this example, I want to convert columns 2 and 3 to percentages (with one decimal point). I can do it with this code:

```
library(scales)
df1 %>%
  mutate(somevariable=try(percent(somevariable),silent = T),
         othervariable=try(percent(othervariable),silent = T))
```

But I'm hoping there is a better way, particularly for the case where I have many columns instead of just 2.

I tried `mutate_each` but I'm doing something wrong...

```
df1 %>%
  mutate_each(funs = try(percent(),silent = T), -name)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach using custom function. This function will only modify numeric vectors, so no need to worry about `try` or removing non-numeric columns. It will also handle `NA`s by defult

```
myfun <- function(x) {
  if(is.numeric(x)){ 
    ifelse(is.na(x), x, paste0(round(x*100L, 1), "%")) 
  } else x 
}

df1 %>% mutate_each(funs(myfun))
#   name somevariable othervariable
# 1   A1        13.4%         53.4%
# 2   A1        54.8%          <NA>
# 3   B1        36.9%         36.9%
# 4   B1         <NA>         33.3%
```

Comment: I think the function would be slightly cleaner with an early return, e.g. `if (!is.numeric(x)) return(x)`

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
df1 %>% 
    mutate_each(funs(try(percent(.), silent=TRUE)), -name)
#   name somevariable othervariable
#1   A1        13.4%         53.4%
#2   A1        54.8%           NA%
#3   B1        36.9%         36.9%
#4   B1          NA%         33.3%
```

if you need to filter out the NAs from getting the percentage,

```
df1 %>% 
    mutate_each(funs(try(ifelse(!is.na(.), percent(.), NA), 
                       silent=TRUE)),-name)
#   name somevariable othervariable
#1   A1        13.4%         53.4%
#2   A1        54.8%          <NA>
#3   B1        36.9%         36.9%
#4   B1         <NA>         33.3%
```

Comment: I wonder in which cases just `df1 %>% mutate_each(funs(percent), -name)` won't do

Comment: @DavidArenburg May be with `factor`. ie. `df1 %>% mutate(val=percent(factor(somevariable)))`

Comment: Oh right, it seems to return and error. My function doesn't though. Not sure what's better

Comment: @DavidArenburg Using your function, returns output with a warning, but with NAs, due to problem with factor

Comment: Yes I know, though using the alternative method on a factor is no better `df1 %>% 
    mutate_each(funs(try(percent(.), silent=TRUE)))`

Comment: We could also modify to `myfun <- function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) paste0(round(x*100L, 1), "%") else x`